# Does to install both Visual C# 2010 Express, and Visual C++ 2010 Express create problems?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

Are there any problems if I install two different IDEs of the Express family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending on klabranche's correct answer.  All express and non-express SKU's of Visual Studio are meant to be installed together.  The only versions of Visual Studio that cannot be installed side by side are different non-express SKU's of the same version.  For example you can't install Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Visual Studio 2010 Professional on the same box.

Comment: Thank you; I was worried that, if I had to uninstall it because I didn't need it, it could remove some files that were still needed from Visual C#.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. They are meant to be installable side by side.